# Retorno em JSON

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, api

Galera, uma dúvida.

Fazendo uma API no NET 5 e usando o EF, quando faço uma consulta de dados relacionados o retorno em JSON dá erro 500.

```
// GET: api/Estadoes/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<List<Cidade>> GetCidade(int id)
    {
        var cidades = await _context.Cidades
                                    .Where(e => e.IdEstado == id)
                                    .Include(c => c.IdEstadoNavigation)
                                    .ToListAsync();

      
        return cidades;
    }
```

Qual forma correta de converter esses dados para JSON?

Comment: Se retornou um 500 é porque provavelmente uma exceção foi estourada. Neste caso, a melhor forma de te ajudar é sabendo qual foi a exceção.

Comment: Error:
Response body
Download
System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_SerializerCycleDetected(Int32 maxDep

Comment: É bem provável que você tenha uma referência circular nos modelos do EF. Tente [edit] a sua pergunta e adicionar as classes referentes ao DbSet de `Cidades` e `Estados`. Dica: remova as propriedades de tipos "básicos" (int, long, string, etc.) e foque nos relacionamentos/navegações.

Answer (score 1):

1. Verifique a versão do **Newtonsoft**
2. Tente o código abaixo:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
```